# Wifi slows down when USB 3 hard drive plugged in

Tags: wireless, usb, hard-drive

Bit of a bizarre problem. I noticed that if I plug in my USB 3 hard drive into a USB 3 slot, network speeds slow down. I've done some (very unscientific) tests on speedtest.net by starting the test with the HDD plugged in (~0.50 Mbps) and, halfway through the test, using the 'safely remove' button in the launcher (goes up to ~5.0 Mbps). I can't reproduce this if I plug the HDD into a USB 2 slot.

The hard drive is formatted as exFAT if that might be relevant. Any ideas?

E: should've mentioned that this is on Ubuntu 15.10.

Thanks!

Comment: I also have same problem on Debian Testing when I connect USB2 encrypted disk (did not try with non encrypted) to USB 3 port. Same problem does not occur on Windows. This is clearly Linux problem. My laptop is lenovo Yoga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is RF interference between USB 3.0 and 2.4 GHz wireless adapters.

See [this report](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/universal-serial-bus/usb3-frequency-interference-paper.html) for more infromation.

This is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the link! Shifting the wireless antenna does seem to help a bit.  
Incidentally, I've booted into Windows on the same machine to try and replicate this, but I can't seem to be able to. Is there some kind of workaround present in Windows for this, and can I somehow apply this to Ubuntu?